# OmniSript Type Ahead Blck Google Maps Autocomplete does not work

Tags: google-map, omnistudio, omniscript, type-ahead

I have created an OmniScript which includes a Type Ahead Block with Google Maps Autocomplete. The component works as expected when I preview the OmniScript and it is capable of displaying matching addresses. However, once the component is activated and embeded in an experience site, the address lookup doesn't work.

I created a new GoogleMapsJavascriptAPI key and removed all the restriction on the key.

When an address is searched on live component, it displays a half loaded line as follows.
[image]

I could observe on Network tab of developer tools that the request to fetch addresses doesn't get a response until around 30 seconds and receives a failure response.
[image]

Following is a sample response for a address fetch request.
[image]

Appreciate any guidence to resolve this issue.

PS:
I was able to isolate the issue further.
Address lookup works if I directly drag and drop the particular Omni component(type/subType/Language) into the builder.

However, it doesn't work if I drag and drop the OminScript compnent and configure it using parameters

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with Google Maps API Key fail with OmniStudio Runtime enabled: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000mNUAUAA4/~

From Salesforce: this issue you are facing is a 'Product bug' and will get fixed in the upcoming future release. Scheduled build for this bug is mentioned as the 246 version. Please refer above given article to track the solution.